# Avoid rollback for an insert statement

Tags: sql-server, transactions, rollback

I have this SQL code that checks for some parameters, if invalid will raise an error, I want also to insert an error record into errors table. the problem is that if error happens the whole transaction will be roll-backed including the error record, I want to rollback the whole transaction except the error record.

I tried creating a separate transaction and commit it with no luck.

```
IF @Input IS NULL
  BEGIN
    insert into  [dbo].Errors('Field1') values ('Input is null')            
    RAISERROR ('some message', 16, 1)
    RETURN -1
  END
```

Is there a way to isolate the insert statement alone in a separate transaction?

Edit:

This stored procedure is called from other procedures and need to be roll-backed, even from outside, so probably i need to separate this insert statement into a separate transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in a separate transaction. No lock changes if the table is locked throughout the course of the transaction, but it does not affect what is rolled back or not. If an error occurs, the whole transaction is rolled back. Can you add a 'try-catch' block to the code that you are calling the stored procedure from? If you 'try' the stored procedure and it throws an error, you should catch the error. In your catch block, you could call a different stored procedure that records the error in the necessary table.

It sounds like the issue that you are having is where to call the stored procedure that records the errors from. This can be tricky and it all depends on how you are handling the transaction and where you are catching the errors. Let's say you have code a that calls code b and b calls the first stored procedure. Now, when the stored procedure throws an error, if you are handling that error in code a, everything that you did in b is rolled back. If you try to insert the error record in code b, that will be rolled back from code a as well.